# max margin for TD vertical align in responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I have a table with 3 column which holds the gallery photos. the right and left column are for arrows. I want the arrows to place vertically in middle of height, but in large screens I want to limit the top margin of arrows to not more than  80px from top of the table. I think am looking for something like "max-margin"! but I can not handle it through pure css.

```
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
   <td style="width:60px;vertical-align:middle"><a>prev</a></td>
   <td>photos here</td>
   <td style="width:60px;vertical-align:middle"><a>next</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Image of what I expect:
[image]

Comment: Hi Sheikhpour, In large screen did you need your arrows to be in vertically middle or 80PX from the top!!!

Comment: I want 80px from top in large screens

Comment: Just use media queries, don't bother with max margin :)

Comment: From the image of what you expect, it looks like you're looking for `max-line-height` really. Which, unfortunately, doesn't exist either. An interesting problem; I don't know why this is being downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like the below example.

```
td {
  vertical-align: middle;     
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    td {
       vertical-align: top;
       margin-top: 80px;
       }
    }
```

It may useful for you.